# What does mapbox understand under a "projected point"?

Tags: mapbox

RMMapView has a method

```
- (RMProjectedPoint)pixelToProjectedPoint:(CGPoint)pixelCoordinate
```

what does  "projected point" mean here?

I also looked at the docs of struct RMProjectedPoint

```
"coordinates, in projected meters, paralleling CGPoint"
```

Can somebody give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can think of this as how many meters from the Prime Meridian and the equator a point is. It's like the rectangular coordinate in the projection of the spherical Earth to a flat surface.